# Using document.getElementsByClassName() instead of id

Tags: javascript

When I try the below using `document.getElementById("stuff")` everything works.

But when I try to do the same by using `document.getElementsByClassName("stuffClass")` it doesn't work.

How can I get this to work by using the `class` instead of an `id`?

```
//var element = document.getElementById("stuff");
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("stuffClass");
var bb = element.getBBox();
var vb = bb.x+" "+bb.y+" "+bb.width+" "+bb.height;
element.setAttribute("viewBox", vb);
```

Comment: have you tried ```document.getElementsByTagName("stuffClass")```?

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns a collection (like an array) you need to access it as such

Comment: Use document.getElementsByClassName("stuffClass")[0]; That'll work

Comment: use `document.querySelector(".stuffClass")`

Comment: @dave: that's beautiful :)

Comment: Learn to use your developer tools console for debugging. You should have seen an error on `element.getBBox`, if you then `console.log("element: ", element)` you would then see it was a collection and not the single element you expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementByClassName` returns a `NodeList`, not a single element. You need to index it:

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("stuffClass")[0];
```

Or if there are multiple elements with the same class, you need to loop over it.

You could also use `document.querySelector`:

```
var element = document.querySelector(".stuffClass");
```

Answer (score 1):

The **javascript** `getElementsByClassName()` method returns a collection of **all elements** in the document with the specified class name, as a `NodeList object`, which represents a collection of `nodes`. Said nodes can be accessed by `index numbers`, similarly to how an array would work.

This means **each element you want to modify must be selected**. For instance, if we wanted to select the second element:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("foo")[1];
```

In order to **modify all elements** with a specified class name, a **loop function** would be required. For instance:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("foo");
for (i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.color = "red";
}
```

You can read more about this matter [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp).